# How to call livewire method in template?

Tags: laravel-livewire

In the component of Laravel 8 / livewire 2 app I selected state(code_id) and I need to preview state and I try to make it with
calling method of the component :

```
{{ getStateLabel($form['state_id']) }}
```

But I got error :

```
Call to undefined function getStateLabel() (View: myproject/resources/views/livewire/personal/new-item.blade.php)
```

In the component I have defined :

```
class NewItem extends Component
{

    public $statesSelectionArray = [];

    public function getStateLabel($state_id= 9)
    {
        foreach( $this->statesSelectionArray as $next_key=>$nextStateSelection ) {
            if($nextStateSelection['id'] == $state_id) {
                return $nextStateSelection['name'];
            }
        }
    }
    ...

}
```

uSIALLY WHEN IN TEMPLATE i CALL COMPONENT METHOD i USE SYNTAX :

```
wire:click="METHODnAME(2);
```

But which syntax have I to use in my case ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $this->getStateLabel({{$value}})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your code like this in your blade file

```
{{ $this->getStateLabel($form['state_id']) }}
```